# Collect any particular attribute value of a fact in a list in drools

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine

I have a pojo similar to below pojo

```
public class TestData {
    int number;
    String name;
    //Getters, setters, rest of class
}
```

The multiple object of this pojo is inserted in the rule engine. Now I want a list having `name attribute` collected from all inserted pojo through rule.
i.e. `List<String>` for the name from the inserted pojo.

Thanks
Shorav

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This very simple rule collects all names in TestData facts:

```
rule "collect names"
when
    accumulate( TestData( $n: name ); $names: collectList( $n ) )
then
    // ... $names is a List containing String objects
end
```

Note that the List `$names` is compiled as a `List<?>`. Processing on the right hand side may have to cast list elements to `String`.